# How to merge two arrays similar to underscore extend method for objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, underscore.js

I have two arrays of arrays with formatted date as key and a number as the corresponding value.

The first array gives me the last seven days using *moment.js* and all values are set to zero.

The second array gives me some meaningful stats for days in the last week if any are present; in the current instance this is only one day that returns any numbers.

I want to merge the second array into the first and retain precedence i.e. that the initial time period array value will be over written with the value from the second array and then return a single array to be used for charting etc.

I tried to do this by converting to objects and using underscore extend method but the sorting is not retained and this is important.

Here is the current code:

```js
var length = 7,
    day = moment(),
    arr = [];

while (length--) {
    arr.push([day.subtract('days', length).format('D MMM'), 0]);
}
```

Which returns an array of arrays for the last seven days e.g.

```js
[["26 Nov", 0], ["27 Nov", 0]]...
```

And then I get the following from my DB query:

```js
[["26 Nov", 6]]
```

So I would like the end result to be:

```js
[["26 Nov", 6], ["27 Nov", 0]]...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native script

```
for(var i=0; i < newArray.length; i++){
    var d=newArray[i][0];
    for( var j= 0; j < oldArray.length ; j++){
         if( oldArray[j][0] ===d){
            oldArray[j][1] = newArray[i][1];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution has quadratic complexity in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Using underscore/lodash you can do something like this, where `newArr` is the data from your db query.

```
merged= _.groupBy(_.union(arr, newArr),function(val){ return val[0]});
var out = _(merged).map(function(val, key) {
   return ([key,_(val).reduce(function(m,x) { return m + x[1]; }, 0)]);
});
```

`merged` is an array where all the duplicate dates (array entry 0) are combined into a single entry,   Then we use a classic map-reduce, with the `reduce` adding up all the values (array entry 1).

http://jsfiddle.net/g9nuC/1/

Side note, for an array of the last 7 days you might prefer:

```
arr.push([day.subtract('days', 1).format('D MMM'), 0]);
```

**Performance**

The solution from @charliefl is approximately 100x faster than underscore (depending on browser) in this case  (and lodash being up to 2x faster than underscore).  Here's a jsperf comparing underscore, lodash and the purely JS solutions:  http://jsperf.com/underscore-vs-native-test-kd/2

Clearly there's ways to mix these two solutions and get different performance results.  I kept this as a purely lodash/underscore solution just to show one endpoint and compare performance results with Charlie's pure JS solution.

And more complex situations will shift the performance balance- anyone can create their own variant of the jsperf to explore that.

Comment: not making fun of you Dave...and I have rarely used underscore...but wow that's hard to glance over when it comes to minor debugging. STrange how in a case like this, native code easier to follow

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I will accept the first response as the answer.  Both are valid so thanks.

Comment: Yea I think this is actually an extreme end of where native is better- which is why I was curious to dig in to the performance results.  As things get more complex, lodash especially really comes into its own.  It'd be really interesting to find some points of performance crossover.

Comment: The accepted solution might be faster for trivial datasets, but this answer has better asymptotic complexity. It grows only linearly in the number of dates, while the accepted answer grows quadratically. This answer however is needlessly complicated. See my own answer for a much more straightforward solution, which is also linear.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will perform the merge in linear time.

```js
function mergeDayRecords(first, second) {
    // First, we create a lookup table so we can find
    // updated data by formatted date.
    var index = _.object(second);

    // For each pair in the first array we want to create a new
    // pair, overriding the value from the second array if present.
    var iteratee = ([date, defaultVal]) => [date, _.get(index, date, defaultVal)];

    // Now we just map this and we're done.
    return _.map(first, iteratee);
}
```

For those using Lodash 4, it's `_.fromPairs` instead of `_.object`.